# Drupal custom content type establishing a parent and child

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, cck, drupal-taxonomy

I am currently building a site on Drupal and I am struggling to work out how to have some parent content (that is created through a custom content type) and some child content that is created through a different custom content type, is this even possibe?

The outcome would be to have some output that would look like this?

- Service Number 1

  - Product Number 1
  - Product Number 2
  - Product Number 3
- Service Number 2

  - Product Number 4
  - Product Number 5
- Service Number 3
- Service Number 4
- Service Number 5

  - Product Number 6
  - Product Number 7

From the list example above you can see that I am wanting to create a nested list that will form some navigation.  I have a content type called "Services" set up and a content type called "poducts" also created, but I see no way of linking products to services.

Should I even be using custom content types for this? Or would better way to do be go down the route of using taxonomies? If that were the case how can I make a taxonomy link to a product or service page, and not it's own  taxonomy page?

I feel like I talk complete nonsense, essestially I cannot work out an uncomplicated way to create a nested navigation in Drupal.

Comment: Are you looking to have links to the items and relevant pages from each item in this navigation?

Comment: @CJBrew yes, so for example I would want service number 1 to link to its pages, and the products to link to their own respective pages

Comment: If this isn't highly dynamic data I might consider using http://drupal.org/project/menu_block, with a specially created menu.
If it is dynamic, you could possibly use views and taxonomy... Might just be easier to write the PHP code into your own module

Answer (score 1):

We get requests for sites structured like this all the time. A combination of these modules always does the trick for me:

- [Node Hierarchy](http://drupal.org/project/nodehierarchy)
- [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block)
- [Menu Trail by Path](http://drupal.org/project/menu_trail_by_path) (optional)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module for this.

Create the two content types: 'Services' and 'Products' and in Products (child) content type, add a mandatory "Entity Reference" field that references to a Services' node (parent).